# Alternative to Escolar ("Butter Fish") for Nigirizushi

Tags: substitutions, fish, sushi

I want to make [Nigirizushi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi#Nigirizushi) with a fish similar to Escolar (also called *Butter Fish*), but prefer not to use that fish.

Are there other fish with a similar taste and texture?

Comment: Healthier in what way? We don't answer questions about health here. Be specific about what you want.

Comment: @Aaronut: well, the main point was to find an alternative with **similar texture** and **similar taste**, the healthy part it's not that important in this case.

Comment: Edited to make this a simple similar fish question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Escolar* is **not** butterfish. It is considered to be more closely related to the [Oilfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oilfish) species.

Butterfishes are from the family [Stromateidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stromateidae), which does *not* include *Escolar*.

As far as I know, there are no digestive issues reported with butterfish. That "wax ester" is highly localized to *Escolar* and Oilfish. So if you're looking for a "substitute", just use *actual butterfish*. Source it from somewhere you trust, or look for a more specific label like *Pomfret* or *Harvestfish*.

Answer (score 2):

The wiki article had some helpful information. In answer to your question, the article included the following quote, "Escolar has been mislabeled or otherwise confused with the following fish: Atlantic cod, oilfish (related to escolar but in a different genus), rudderfish, blue cod, black cod, king tuna, grouper, orange roughy, sea bass, gemfish, Chilean sea bass, albacore tuna, and white tuna."

The wiki article, which includes more information that you might find of interest based on your question prior to edit, can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escolar